# Describe the state of stress in a deformed elastic body with a given Cauchy Stress Tensor

Tags: tensors

How can I describe the state of stress in a deformed elastic body if the corresponding Cauchy stress tensor $T$ is constant and given by $T = −pI$, where $p > 0$ ??

Answer (score 0):

This is really a physics question. Your Cauchy stress tensor is of the form $-p I$ everywhere, which corresponds to a uniform, hydrostatic, compressive state of stress in the body.

You can easily check that the matrix of components of this tensor is the same in any coordinate system since it is just a scalar multiple times the identity tensor (Thus, you have a hydrostatic stress state). The sign of the coefficient $p$ determines whether you have tensile or compressive hydrostatic stress.